# Why can't I have return types covariant with void*?

Tags: c++, covariance, return-type

Why is the following code a covariance error? Isn't `T *` covariant with `void *`...?

```
struct Base { virtual void *foo(); };
struct Derived : Base { int *foo(); };
```

GCC says:

```
invalid covariant return type for 'virtual int* Derived::foo()'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[class.virtual]/p7, emphasis mine:

> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to
>   the return type of the overridden function or *covariant* with the
>   classes of the functions. If a function `D::f` overrides a function
>   `B::f`, the return types of the functions are covariant if they
>   satisfy the following criteria:
>
> - both are pointers to **classes**, both are lvalue references to **classes**, or both are rvalue references to **classes** [footnote omitted]
> - [...]

---

From pages 294-5 of [D&E](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html):

> Afer some consideration of the alternatives, we decided to allow
>   overriding of a `B*` by a `D*` and of a `B&` by a `D&` where `B` is an
>   accessible base of `D`. In addition, `const` can be added or
>   subtracted wherever that is safe. We decided not to relax the rules to
>   allow technically feasible conversions such as a `D` to an accessible
>   base `B`, a `D` to an `X` for which `D` has a conversion, `int*` to
>   `void*`, `double` to `int`, etc. We felt that the benefits from
>   allowing such conversions through overriding would not outweigh the
>   implementation cost and the potential for confusing users.

Comment: Would be nice if you could explain the "why" behind this design.

Comment: @Mehrdad Added a D&E quote.

Comment: When I look at the problem with the covariance and limitations of namespaces in C++ then I can discern the reasoning behind Java's Object and packages.

Answer (score 1):

The covariance between `void*` and `T*` is not allowed because:

**1. lack of consistency**.

The current way of covariance is trivial to understand and doesn't create confusion.
Just imagine of `void*` type of covariance is allowed. For 1 stage of derivation is fine, but then it will create confusion. e.g.:

```
struct void_ { virtual void* foo (); };
struct int_ : void_ { virtual int* foo (); };
struct double_ : int_ { virtual double* foo (); };  // int* to double* or void* to double*
```

In the 3rd hierarchy of `struct double_`, the user will be confused that even though `double*` to `int*` is not possible, why the code is still compiling? Only after checking the top most class `void_`, it's known that it is because of `double*` to `void*` is "covariant". Same goes for compiler as well :-)

**2. Issue with the references**

In case of classes, returning `B&`/`D*`/`DD*` is possible. But same thing is not possible with `void&` and hence `int&` etc.

**3. Mixing of covariances**

If `void*` is allowed then following is also allowed unintentionally.

```
struct void_ { virtual void* foo (); };
struct Base : void_ { virtual Base* foo (); };
struct Derived : Base { virtual int* foo (); }; // Look at `int*`
```

Which adds up to confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Covariant return type feature is when, a derived class provides a more specific/narrower return type for a overridden function. The derived class return type is said to be covariant.

int* is not of type void* whereas something like this does depict covariant return type:

```
struct Base {
  virtual void *foo();
  virtual Base* func();
};
struct Derived : Base {
//  int *foo();
  Derived* func(); //COVARIANT RETURN TYPE
};
```

Comment: You are explaining the definition of "Covariance", the OP is asking "Why".